# How do you pass an NSData from JavaScript?

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I'm creating a native module which uses the CoreBluetooth.framework. I'm trying to implement an `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` that will call [this bluetooth write method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:).

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(write:(CBUUID *)peripheralUuid 
                  forCharacteristicUuid:(CBUUID *)characteristicUuid 
                  data:(NSData *)data /* <== HOW DO I PASS THIS IN? */
                  withResponse:(BOOL)withResponse)
{
    CBPeripheral *peripheral = /* my peripheral */;
    CBCharacteristic *characteristic = /* my characteristic */;

    if (peripheral && characteristic) {
        [peripheral 
              writeValue:data 
              forCharacteristic:characteristic 
              type:withResponse ? 0 : 1];
    }
}
```

What do I need to do with `RCTConvert` to get the `NSData` argument through the native bridge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further research into the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/da0744892c64f9bff128338e863fa45b3fc71986/React/Base/RCTConvert.m#L58) I found that you can't declare an `NSData` argument, you have to pass it in as a base64 encoded string (`NSString`) and then use `RCTConvert` to convert it to an `NSData`.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(write:(CBUUID *)peripheralUuid 
                  forCharacteristicUuid:(CBUUID *)characteristicUuid 
                  data:(NSString *)data
                  withResponse:(BOOL)withResponse)
{
    // ....
    [peripheral 
          writeValue:[RCTConvert NSData:data] 
          forCharacteristic:/* ... */
          type:/* ... */];
}
```

Comment: This is strange, calling `[RCTConvert NSData:data]` on the argument should behave exactly the same as defining it as `data:(NSData *)data`. From JS end, you still pass it as a Base64-encoded string.