# How to pass NSData from javascript to swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, nsdata

I am trying to call the write method of CoreBluetooth from react-native. I have created a mediator class and created a **write** method on it.
Here it is:

```
  @objc func write(_ serviceUUID: String, _ charecteristicsUUID: String, _ data: NSData){
    
  }
```

I'm creating a native module that uses the CoreBluetooth.framework. I'm trying to implement an `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` that will call this Bluetooth write method. I am trying to call it from javascript but I don't have any idea how to pass **NSData** from the javascript to swift native module.

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008703/how-do-you-pass-an-nsdata-from-javascript). This is not working as expected.

Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895485/calling-native-swift-code-from-javascript-using-javascriptcore-and-jscontext

Comment: @RB's your answer sadly did not solve my problem. I already call simple method of nativet to react native. But I want to call method with NSData argument.

Comment: You cannot, React Native only allows a subset of types to be passed https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#argument-types You need to encode your NSData as a String and decode it on the other side.